# Select data from one Activity and side by side instant change in Another Activity or fragment in android

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

Sorry for my bad English.
I have a spinner(with some city list) and a tab layout(say tabA and tabB) in my mainActivity.TabA and TabB have separate fragment. My Question is when I select spinner item from mainActivity then at the same time tab A data will load. Is that possible that we can change data from one class and changes will be made in another class.

Or if you have a better solution then please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: create interface for your activity and get update from that interface in another fragment

Comment: @tejas yes your concept is correct thanks. But i need an example. So please give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data from one activity to another activity using intends. Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, destinationActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

This will send the `value` to destinationActivity assigned to a variable `key`.

In your destinationActivity, you can get the value of `key` and write your code accordingly. Like this:

```
String key= getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

Here, `value` will be stored in `key` variable.

Hop this helps :)

Comment: This is not my question's solutions. Please see my question again and give me a proper answer.

Comment: @GuruRathore `give me a proper answer` . you seems too rude

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by means of a interface. When you need to change the value of  class B just call a interface(that is implemented in class B) from current class A and do whatever you want.